# 404 message with PHP: Post values HTML with text and dropdown values

Tags: php, html, http-status-code-404, form-submit

I have a basic form for a website that when submitted is emailed to my client. I used this form before and it worked fine. The client wanted to add a few more text sections and a dropdown list.

I added the list option in html and kept the same variables in php.

**PHP**

```
<?php

if( ! empty( $honeypot ) ){
        return; 
    }else{
        mail( $to, $subject, $message, $header );
    }


    /* Email Variables */
    $emailSubject = 'solutions_form'; /*Make sure this matches the name of your file*/
    $webMaster = '#';
    
    /* Data Variables */
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $organization = $_POST['organization'];
    $industry = $_POST['industry'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $website = $_POST['website'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $employees = $_POST['employees'];
    $honeypot = $_POST['_honey'];
    
    
    
    $body = <<<EOD
    <br><hr><br>
    Name: $name <br>
    Email: $email <br>
    Organization: $organization <br>
    Industry: $industry <br>
    Phone: $phone <br>
    Website: $website <br>
    Message: $message <br>
    Employees: $employees <br>
    
    EOD;
    $headers = "From: $email\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
    $success = mail($webMaster, $emailSubject, $body,
    $headers);
    
    
    /* Results rendered as HTML */
    $theResults = <<<EOD
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>sent message</title>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;URL=*****
    
    <style type="text/css">
    <!--
    body {
    background-color: #1d2d49; /* You can edit this CSS to match your website*/
    font-family:Montserrant, sans-serif;
    font-size: 32px;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #FFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin:auto;
    width: auto;
    padding-top:250px;
    }
    -->
    </style>
    </head>
    <div align="center">Thank you for your message! <br /> We will be in touch with you shortly.</div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
    EOD;
    echo "$theResults";
    ?>
```

Now when hitting submit, I get a 404 page not found. I'm obviously leaving out the rest of the HTML and PHP so it isn't unnecessarily long. And I have looked throughout old questions and the answers that worked for others do not seem to work for me. I'm using POST. Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Sorry, but there is simply not enough detail here for us to even take a guess. 404 means that the page is not found. It seems unlikely that adding new parameter would cause the issue

Comment: I also updated the question with full PHP

Comment: [link]https://jsfiddle.net/closet_breaker/c3zdmtwf/2/#&togetherjs=vRDaCMDCCp